# currency parsing and conversion using shell commands

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I'm looking for a shell one-liner that will parse the following example currency string **PHP10000** into **$245**. I need to parse the number from the string, multiply it with a preset conversion factor then add a "$" prefix to the result.

So far, what I have is only this:

```
echo PHP10000 | sed -e 's/PHP//'
```

which gives `10000` as result.

Now, I'm stuck on how to do multiplication on that result.

I'm thinking `awk` could also give a solution to this but I'm a beginner at shell commands.

**Update:**

I tried:

```
echo PHP10000 | expr `sed -e 's/PHP//'` \* 2
```

and the multiplication works properly only on whole numbers. I can't use floating point numbers as it gives me this error: `expr: not a decimal number: '2.1'`.

Comment: I defy anyone to explain to me what this has to do with math.  At least remove that tag.

Comment: Depending on the purpose of this, you may need more decimal places than has been suggested, although you might get "lucky" whilst you retain such a "friendly" multiplicand/divisor. Change that a little, run with 1000 examples in PHP, add up the PHP values and the USD values, convert the PHP total to USD and compare the two USD values. If you are just converting "prices" for a shop or catalog or something, OK. If you are doing something financial, you'll need a bit more work.

Comment: @duffymo: I tagged it with math since I basically wanted to do math operations on the shell.

Comment: @BillWoodger: The purpose of this one liner is to process text files on the shell, search for currencies in the text, then convert them into the target currency.

Comment: It's not math; it's just "I don't know how to parse with PHP".

Comment: @duffymo: it's shell scripting not PHP. PHP here stands for Philippine peso (a currency unit).

Comment: @dashmug - Okay, then you don't know how to parse in the shell script.  Still not math - not even close.

Comment: @duffymo: We're not debating the "math" part anymore. That tag has already been removed. And yes, I don't know how to parse it using a shell script. That's the whole point of this question. What's yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
echo "PHP10000" | awk -F "PHP" '{ printf "$%d\n", $2 * .0245 }'
```

Results:

```
$245
```

Or to print to two decimal places:

```
echo "PHP10000" | awk -F "PHP" '{ printf "$%.2f\n", $2 * .0245 }'
```

Results:

```
$245.00
```

**EDIT:**

Bash doesn't support floating point operations. Use `bc` instead:

```
echo "PHP10000" | sed 's/PHP\([0-9]\+\)/echo "scale=2; \1*.0245\/1" | bc/e'
```

Results:

```
245.00
```

Comment: _Bash doesn't support floating point operations_ - the calculation is done by awk, not sure why you mention bash.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Sorry if that is not clear. I'm actually referring to the OP's comments under "Update". He's trying to use `sed` and `bash`. I'm saying he need's to use `bc` to get decimal numbers _if_ he wants not to use `awk`. HTH.

Comment: You can pass the conversion factor as a parameter so it does not need to be hard-coded: `convfact=0.0245; awk -F "PHP" -v factor="$convfact" '{ printf "$%d\n", $2 * factor }'`

Answer (score 2):

```
value=PHP10000
factor=40.82
printf -v converted '$%.2f' "$(bc <<< "${value#PHP} / $factor")"
echo $converted    # => $244.98
```

- the `${value#PHP}` part is [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) that removes the PHP string from the front of the `$value` string
- the `<<<` part is a bash [here-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings), so you're passing the formula to the bc program
- bash does not do floating point arithmetic, so call [`bc`](http://man.cx/bc) to perform the calculation
- `printf -v varname` is the equivalent of other languages `varname = sprintf(...)`

Comment: +1 Cool use of `printf`. I too originally used the magical number 40.8 for my calcs. But after re-reading the question a few times, I'm almost certain the OP means multiply by 0.0245. HTH.

Comment: well, divide by x or multiply by 1/x -- same result.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
echo PHP10000 | awk '/PHP/ { printf "$%.0f\n", .0245 * substr($1,4) }'
```

It can be easily extended to a multi-currency version that converts into one currency (known as quote currency), e.g.:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    rates["PHPUSD"]=.01
    rates["GBPUSD"]=1.58
}
/[A-Z]{3}[0-9.]+/ {
    pair=substr($1,1,3) "USD"
    amount=substr($1,4)
    print "USD" amount * rates[pair]
}
' <<EOF
PHP100
GBP100
EOF
```

Outputs:

```
USD1
USD158
```

Comment: Wow, that's a good one! May I ask though, what does the "4" mean in `substr($1,4)`?

Comment: Means starting at position 4, and with no length specified, means up to the end of the string. Is your data solely currency amounts, and only one per record?

Comment: @dashmug It is a function that returns a sub-string. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative:

```
$ echo "PHP10000" | awk 'sub(/PHP/,""){ print "$" $0 * .0245 }'
$245
```